# SQL - how to evaluate on parameter IF the parameter meets certain conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I've got some pretty basic SQL code, below:

```
SELECT 
    Area.Id AS 'Id'
    , Area.Code
    , Area.Description
From Area WHERE ClientId=@ClientId
    and (id in (@AreaParam)
```

Now, this is all fine and dandy when the user sends in the ClientId and AreaParam parameters (the AreaParam contains a list, like 1,2,3 etc).

**However**, what I'm wanting it to do is, if the user sends in an AreaParam of, say, null or an arbitrary value (such as -1), not do the AreaParam check. So basically a case on the AreaParam, or something like that.

Comment: `and (id in (@AreaParam) or @AreaParam = -1)`

Comment: Excellent - thank you, works perfectly.